# Ruby: inject issue when turning array into hash

Tags: ruby

```
a = [[1, 'a'],[2, 'b'],[3, 'c'], [4, 'd']]
a.inject({}) {|r, val| r[val[0]] = val[1]}
```

When I run this, I get an index error

When I change the block to

```
a.inject({}) {|r, val| r[val[0]] = val[1]; r}
```

It then works.

How is ruby handling the first inject attempt that isn't getting what I want?
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: +1 For asking a question exactly relevant to something I was trying to do, thus being helpful. ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just because Ruby is dynamically and implicitly typed doesn't mean that you don't have to think about types.

The type of `Enumerable#inject` without an explicit accumulator (this is usually called `reduce`) is something like

```
reduce :: [a] → (a → a → a) → a
```

or in a more Rubyish notation I just made up

```
Enumerable[A]#inject {|A, A| A } → A
```

You will notice that all the types are the same. The element type of the `Enumerable`, the two argument types of the block, the return type of the block and the return type of the overall method.

The type of `Enumerable#inject` *with* an explicit accumulator (this is usually called `fold`) is something like

```
fold :: [b] → a → (a → b → a) → a
```

or

```
Enumerable[B]#inject(A) {|A, B| A } → A
```

Here you see that the accumulator can have a *different* type than the element type of the collection.

These two rules generally get you through all `Enumerable#inject`-related type problems:

1. the type of the accumulator and the return type of the block must be the same
2. when not passing an explicit accumulator, the type of the accumulator is the same as the element type

In this case, it is Rule #1 that bites you. When you do something like

```
acc[key] = value
```

in your block, assignments evaluate to the assigned value, not the receiver of the assignment. You'll have to replace this with

```
acc.tap { acc[key] = value }
```

See also [Why Ruby inject method cannot sum up string lengths without initial value?](http://StackOverflow.Com/a/4314292/2988/)

---

BTW: you can use destructuring bind to make your code much more readable:

```
a.inject({}) {|r, (key, value)| r[key] = value; r }
```

Comment: Oh, so inject is a fold operation. That makes sense then.

Comment: Yes, `inject` is Ruby's (actually, Smalltalk's) name for `fold` / `reduce`. BTW: It's refreshing to *not* get a blank stare when saying "`inject` is just a `fold`" :-)

Answer (score 9):

There is an easier way -

```
a = [[1, 'a'],[2, 'b'],[3, 'c'], [4, 'd']]
b = Hash[a] # {1=>"a", 2=>"b", 3=>"c", 4=>"d"}
```

The reason the first method isn't working, is because inject uses the result of the block as the `r` in the next iteration. For the first iteration, `r` is set to the argument you pass to it, which in this case is `{}`.

Comment: +1; doesn't explain anything, but *is* a better way (if example code is really what they're doing)--part two of the question.

Answer (score 4):

The first block returns the result of the assignment back into the `inject`, the second returns the hash, so it actually works.

A lot of people consider this usage of `inject` an anti-pattern; consider [`each_with_object` instead](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_object).

Comment: @Chuck Correct, if the OP's code is exactly what they're trying to do, I agree. I was answering the first part.

Comment: Personally I don't think that this is an anti-pattern for a fold. If explicitly having to return the hash bothers you, just use a different method: `a.inject({}) { |r, (k, v)| r.merge(k => v) }` (or `merge!` if the throwaway hashes bother you).

Comment: @MichaelKohl I didn't say *I* did... although if I was forced to take a side, I'd be against it on the elegance principle.

Answer (score 3):

```
a.inject({}) { |r, val| r.merge({ val[0] => val[1] }) }
```