# Why does storing intermediary sums break my use of Ruby's inject method?

Tags: ruby

I want to use `inject` and also store intermediary values in an array. Here is the code:

```
store_value = []
[1,2,3].inject(0) do |sum, n|
  store_value << sum + n
end
```

I get this error:

```
no implicit conversion of Fixnum into Array (TypeError)
```

I don't understand why. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: try appending just `sum`?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 almost. The simplest fix would be to return `sum + n`, not `sum`. That's a little duplicative, thus my answer.

Comment: BTW: this operation is called *scan* or *prefix sum*, and is available in e.g. Haskell's and Scala's standard library, but unfortunately not in Ruby.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10576460/2988

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The block passed to `inject` needs to return the memo (sum in your case). Appending to an array returns the array, not the value appended. So, in your code, the first time the block is executed `sum` becomes [1], and the second time it's executed `sum + n` is `[1] + 2`, which gives you the error you see.

Fix it by returning the sum from the block:

```
store_value = []
[1,2,3].inject(0) do |sum, n|
  sum += n
  store_value << sum
  sum
end
```

Or use `tap` to get the appending out of the way:

```
store_value = []
[1,2,3].inject(0) do |sum, n|
  (sum + n).tap { |new_sum| store_value << new_sum }
end
```

Comment: The other option would be to make the array the accumulator: `[1,2,3].inject([0]) {|prefix, n| prefix << prefix.last + n }`. Or, if you want to keep the two separate: `[1,2,3].inject([[], 0]) {|(prefix, sum), n| prefix + [sum + n] }`